# google.com versus google [.pl | .fr | .ca | ...] SHA-256 fingerprint?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

Can someone explain me why when i check www.google.ca certificate with openssl cli, result is different of what i see in my browser :

> $ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.google.ca:443 |& openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout SHA256 Fingerprint=51:45:70:26:0D:90:83:07:99:BC:59:05:A9:87:0F:00:25:07:11:2F:49:BD:61:1A:88:E1:F7:7D:3D:1A:53:16

In my browser, certficate is :

E0 0B 85 15 B2 53 84 09 C3 EE 2E CD 75 29 94 89 5D 0A 8F 75 0F 0F 94 0C D7 35 95 6A 50 AF 4D 5B

My check is working with www.facebook.com.

> $ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.facebook.com:443 |& openssl
>   x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout SHA256
>   Fingerprint=A6:26:B1:54:CC:65:63:41:81:25:0B:81:0B:1B:D4:C8:9E:C2:77:CE:A0:8D:78:5E:EB:E7:E7:68:BD:A7:BB:00

I can see this SHA-256 fingerprint in Chrome :

A6 26 B1 54 CC 65 63 41 81 25 0B 81 0B 1B D4 C8 9E C2 77 CE A0 8D 78 5E EB E7 E7 68 BD A7 BB 00

Check is working for www.google.com but not other tld' s. I guess Google is doing something for .ca/.fr/.pl (always same fingerprint ?)... But i don't get it in detail.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT 1**

Here is detail certificate for www.google.pl :

> $ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.google.pl:443 |& openssl x509
>   -fingerprint -sha256 -noout SHA256 Fingerprint=51:45:70:26:0D:90:83:07:99:BC:59:05:A9:87:0F:00:25:07:11:2F:49:BD:61:1A:88:E1:F7:7D:3D:1A:53:16

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.google.pl:443 |& openssl x509  -text |more
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 717608466795509036 (0x9f575193728b52c)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=Google Inc, CN=Google Internet Authority G2
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar  2 11:17:08 2016 GMT
            Not After : May 31 00:00:00 2016 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc, CN=google.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c3:c7:c6:b6:eb:a9:d4:4e:76:f6:74:0b:77:dd:
                    1c:7c:91:85:00:55:60:f2:e9:9e:d8:b5:c7:b6:92:
                    93:46:8a:94:48:35:89:04:c0:b8:bf:56:d7:c0:f6:
                    a9:11:1c:74:a1:43:b9:e2:c8:24:12:9a:70:c7:5d:
                    c5:85:71:ca:a8:8d:a7:87:e3:5e:25:d9:72:db:49:
                    d0:ff:52:29:ab:ff:6b:25:7c:96:dc:5a:58:8e:b8:
                    b1:99:c3:12:3c:a2:8b:a9:5a:82:d7:3b:70:50:26:
                    1d:8c:75:a1:ce:b0:0c:50:9a:95:bc:19:2e:d6:60:
                    e9:8c:bd:03:aa:97:5d:23:ae:dc:ff:d9:c0:c7:82:
                    8f:5e:8a:11:b0:76:13:3d:13:28:99:8a:63:47:04:
                    06:9d:7b:77:7a:ab:38:ef:da:60:0d:01:58:6c:e4:
                    71:e8:c1:66:bb:b2:07:ee:6b:1d:3f:33:f0:48:06:
                    49:c3:fe:2e:58:89:5c:63:ff:3d:e5:fb:74:85:4f:
                    b0:55:a7:3c:e0:73:38:1b:dc:4e:55:66:60:9e:dd:
                    24:9d:5a:b7:b7:a3:33:42:04:ab:71:f1:0c:d7:ee:
                    f0:06:df:80:ad:e5:8f:d5:2f:c2:86:8a:98:8e:80:
                    f6:85:bb:26:2a:f5:5c:bc:ec:8d:c3:71:70:14:35:
                    b7:85
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:google.com, DNS:*.2mdn.net, DNS:*.android.com, DNS:*.appengine.google.com, DNS:*.au.doubleclick.net, DNS:*.cc-dt.com, DNS:*.cloud.google.com, D
NS:*.de.doubleclick.net, DNS:*.doubleclick.com, DNS:*.doubleclick.net, DNS:*.fls.doubleclick.net, DNS:*.fr.doubleclick.net, DNS:*.google-analytics.com, DNS:*.googl
e.ac, DNS:*.google.ad, DNS:*.google.ae, DNS:*.google.af, DNS:*.google.ag, DNS:*.google.al, DNS:*.google.am, DNS:*.google.as, DNS:*.google.at, DNS:*.google.az, DNS:
*.google.ba, DNS:*.google.be, DNS:*.google.bf, DNS:*.google.bg, DNS:*.google.bi, DNS:*.google.bj, DNS:*.google.bs, DNS:*.google.bt, DNS:*.google.by, DNS:*.google.c
a, DNS:*.google.cat, DNS:*.google.cc, DNS:*.google.cd, DNS:*.google.cf, DNS:*.google.cg, DNS:*.google.ch, DNS:*.google.ci, DNS:*.google.cl, DNS:*.google.cm, DNS:*.
google.cn, DNS:*.google.co.ao, DNS:*.google.co.bw, DNS:*.google.co.ck, DNS:*.google.co.cr, DNS:*.google.co.hu, DNS:*.google.co.id, DNS:*.google.co.il, DNS:*.google
.co.im, DNS:*.google.co.in, DNS:*.google.co.je, DNS:*.google.co.jp, DNS:*.google.co.ke, DNS:*.google.co.kr, DNS:*.google.co.ls, DNS:*.google.co.ma, DNS:*.google.co
.mz, DNS:*.google.co.nz, DNS:*.google.co.th, DNS:*.google.co.tz, DNS:*.google.co.ug, DNS:*.google.co.uk, DNS:*.google.co.uz, DNS:*.google.co.ve, DNS:*.google.co.vi
, DNS:*.google.co.za, DNS:*.google.co.zm, DNS:*.google.co.zw, DNS:*.google.com, DNS:*.google.com.af, DNS:*.google.com.ag, DNS:*.google.com.ai, DNS:*.google.com.ar,
 DNS:*.google.com.au, DNS:*.google.com.bd, DNS:*.google.com.bh, DNS:*.google.com.bn, DNS:*.google.com.bo, DNS:*.google.com.br, DNS:*.google.com.by, DNS:*.google.co
m.bz, DNS:*.google.com.cn, DNS:*.google.com.co, DNS:*.google.com.cu, DNS:*.google.com.cy, DNS:*.google.com.do, DNS:*.google.com.ec, DNS:*.google.com.eg, DNS:*.goog
le.com.et, DNS:*.google.com.fj, DNS:*.google.com.ge, DNS:*.google.com.gh, DNS:*.google.com.gi, DNS:*.google.com.gr, DNS:*.google.com.gt, DNS:*.google.com.hk, DNS:*
.google.com.iq, DNS:*.google.com.jm, DNS:*.google.com.jo, DNS:*.google.com.kh, DNS:*.google.com.kw, DNS:*.google.com.lb, DNS:*.google.com.ly, DNS:*.google.com.mm, 
DNS:*.google.com.mt, DNS:*.google.com.mx, DNS:*.google.com.my, DNS:*.google.com.na, DNS:*.google.com.nf, DNS:*.google.com.ng, DNS:*.google.com.ni, DNS:*.google.com
.np, DNS:*.google.com.nr, DNS:*.google.com.om, DNS:*.google.com.pa, DNS:*.google.com.pe, DNS:*.google.com.pg, DNS:*.google.com.ph, DNS:*.google.com.pk, DNS:*.googl
e.com.pl, DNS:*.google.com.pr, DNS:*.google.com.py, DNS:*.google.com.qa, DNS:*.google.com.ru, DNS:*.google.com.sa, DNS:*.google.com.sb, DNS:*.google.com.sg, DNS:*.
google.com.sl, DNS:*.google.com.sv, DNS:*.google.com.tj, DNS:*.google.com.tn, DNS:*.google.com.tr, DNS:*.google.com.tw, DNS:*.google.com.ua, DNS:*.google.com.uy, D
NS:*.google.com.vc, DNS:*.google.com.ve, DNS:*.google.com.vn, DNS:*.google.cv, DNS:*.google.cz, DNS:*.google.de, DNS:*.google.dj, DNS:*.google.dk, DNS:*.google.dm,
 DNS:*.google.dz, DNS:*.google.ee, DNS:*.google.es, DNS:*.google.eus, DNS:*.google.fi, DNS:*.google.fm, DNS:*.google.fr, DNS:*.google.frl, DNS:*.google.ga, DNS:*.g
oogle.gal, DNS:*.google.ge, DNS:*.google.gg, DNS:*.google.gl, DNS:*.google.gm, DNS:*.google.gp, DNS:*.google.gr, DNS:*.google.gy, DNS:*.google.hk, DNS:*.google.hn,
 DNS:*.google.hr, DNS:*.google.ht, DNS:*.google.hu, DNS:*.google.ie, DNS:*.google.im, DNS:*.google.in, DNS:*.google.info, DNS:*.google.iq, DNS:*.google.ir, DNS:*.g
oogle.is, DNS:*.google.it, DNS:*.google.it.ao, DNS:*.google.je, DNS:*.google.jo, DNS:*.google.jobs, DNS:*.google.jp, DNS:*.google.kg, DNS:*.google.ki, DNS:*.google
.kz, DNS:*.google.la, DNS:*.google.li, DNS:*.google.lk, DNS:*.google.lt, DNS:*.google.lu, DNS:*.google.lv, DNS:*.google.md, DNS:*.google.me, DNS:*.google.mg, DNS:*
.google.mk, DNS:*.google.ml, DNS:*.google.mn, DNS:*.google.ms, DNS:*.google.mu, DNS:*.google.mv, DNS:*.google.mw, DNS:*.google.ne, DNS:*.google.ne.jp, DNS:*.google
.net, DNS:*.google.ng, DNS:*.google.nl, DNS:*.google.no, DNS:*.google.nr, DNS:*.google.nu, DNS:*.google.off.ai, DNS:*.google.pk, DNS:*.google.pl, DNS:*.google.pn, 
DNS:*.google.ps, DNS:*.google.pt, DNS:*.google.ro, DNS:*.google.rs, DNS:*.google.ru, DNS:*.google.rw, DNS:*.google.sc, DNS:*.google.se, DNS:*.google.sh, DNS:*.goog
le.si, DNS:*.google.sk, DNS:*.google.sm, DNS:*.google.sn, DNS:*.google.so, DNS:*.google.sr, DNS:*.google.st, DNS:*.google.td, DNS:*.google.tel, DNS:*.google.tg, DN
S:*.google.tk, DNS:*.google.tl, DNS:*.google.tm, DNS:*.google.tn, DNS:*.google.to, DNS:*.google.tt, DNS:*.google.ua, DNS:*.google.us, DNS:*.google.uz, DNS:*.google
.vg, DNS:*.google.vu, DNS:*.google.ws, DNS:*.googleadapis.com, DNS:*.googleadsserving.cn, DNS:*.googleapis.cn, DNS:*.googlecommerce.com, DNS:*.googleusercontent.cn
, DNS:*.googlevideo.com, DNS:*.gstatic.cn, DNS:*.gstatic.com, DNS:*.gvt1.com, DNS:*.gvt2.com, DNS:*.jp.doubleclick.net, DNS:*.metric.gstatic.com, DNS:*.uk.doublecl
ick.net, DNS:*.urchin.com, DNS:*.url.google.com, DNS:*.youtube-nocookie.com, DNS:*.youtube.com, DNS:*.youtubeeducation.com, DNS:*.ytimg.com, DNS:ad.mo.doubleclick.
net, DNS:android.clients.google.com, DNS:android.com, DNS:doubleclick.net, DNS:g.co, DNS:goo.gl, DNS:google-analytics.com, DNS:google.ac, DNS:google.ad, DNS:google
.ae, DNS:google.af, DNS:google.ag, DNS:google.al, DNS:google.am, DNS:google.as, DNS:google.at, DNS:google.az, DNS:google.ba, DNS:google.be, DNS:google.bf, DNS:goog
le.bg, DNS:google.bi, DNS:google.bj, DNS:google.bs, DNS:google.bt, DNS:google.by, DNS:google.ca, DNS:google.cat, DNS:google.cc, DNS:google.cd, DNS:google.cf, DNS:g
oogle.cg, DNS:google.ch, DNS:google.ci, DNS:google.cl, DNS:google.cm, DNS:google.cn, DNS:google.co.ao, DNS:google.co.bw, DNS:google.co.ck, DNS:google.co.cr, DNS:go
ogle.co.hu, DNS:google.co.id, DNS:google.co.il, DNS:google.co.im, DNS:google.co.in, DNS:google.co.je, DNS:google.co.jp, DNS:google.co.ke, DNS:google.co.kr, DNS:goo
gle.co.ls, DNS:google.co.ma, DNS:google.co.mz, DNS:google.co.nz, DNS:google.co.th, DNS:google.co.tz, DNS:google.co.ug, DNS:google.co.uk, DNS:google.co.uz, DNS:goog
le.co.ve, DNS:google.co.vi, DNS:google.co.za, DNS:google.co.zm, DNS:google.co.zw, DNS:google.com.af, DNS:google.com.ag, DNS:google.com.ai, DNS:google.com.ar, DNS:g
oogle.com.au, DNS:google.com.bd, DNS:google.com.bh, DNS:google.com.bn, DNS:google.com.bo, DNS:google.com.br, DNS:google.com.by, DNS:google.com.bz, DNS:google.com.c
n, DNS:google.com.co, DNS:google.com.cu, DNS:google.com.cy, DNS:google.com.do, DNS:google.com.ec, DNS:google.com.eg, DNS:google.com.et, DNS:google.com.fj, DNS:goog
le.com.ge, DNS:google.com.gh, DNS:google.com.gi, DNS:google.com.gr, DNS:google.com.gt, DNS:google.com.hk, DNS:google.com.iq, DNS:google.com.jm, DNS:google.com.jo, 
DNS:google.com.kh, DNS:google.com.kw, DNS:google.com.lb, DNS:google.com.ly, DNS:google.com.mm, DNS:google.com.mt, DNS:google.com.mx, DNS:google.com.my, DNS:google.
com.na, DNS:google.com.nf, DNS:google.com.ng, DNS:google.com.ni, DNS:google.com.np, DNS:google.com.nr, DNS:google.com.om, DNS:google.com.pa, DNS:google.com.pe, DNS
:google.com.pg, DNS:google.com.ph, DNS:google.com.pk, DNS:google.com.pl, DNS:google.com.pr, DNS:google.com.py, DNS:google.com.qa, DNS:google.com.ru, DNS:google.com
.sa, DNS:google.com.sb, DNS:google.com.sg, DNS:google.com.sl, DNS:google.com.sv, DNS:google.com.tj, DNS:google.com.tn, DNS:google.com.tr, DNS:google.com.tw, DNS:go
ogle.com.ua, DNS:google.com.uy, DNS:google.com.vc, DNS:google.com.ve, DNS:google.com.vn, DNS:google.cv, DNS:google.cz, DNS:google.de, DNS:google.dj, DNS:google.dk,
 DNS:google.dm, DNS:google.dz, DNS:google.ee, DNS:google.es, DNS:google.eus, DNS:google.fi, DNS:google.fm, DNS:google.fr, DNS:google.frl, DNS:google.ga, DNS:google
.gal, DNS:google.ge, DNS:google.gg, DNS:google.gl, DNS:google.gm, DNS:google.gp, DNS:google.gr, DNS:google.gy, DNS:google.hk, DNS:google.hn, DNS:google.hr, DNS:goo
gle.ht, DNS:google.hu, DNS:google.ie, DNS:google.im, DNS:google.in, DNS:google.info, DNS:google.iq, DNS:google.ir, DNS:google.is, DNS:google.it, DNS:google.it.ao, 
DNS:google.je, DNS:google.jo, DNS:google.jobs, DNS:google.jp, DNS:google.kg, DNS:google.ki, DNS:google.kz, DNS:google.la, DNS:google.li, DNS:google.lk, DNS:google.
lt, DNS:google.lu, DNS:google.lv, DNS:google.md, DNS:google.me, DNS:google.mg, DNS:google.mk, DNS:google.ml, DNS:google.mn, DNS:google.ms, DNS:google.mu, DNS:googl
e.mv, DNS:google.mw, DNS:google.ne, DNS:google.ne.jp, DNS:google.net, DNS:google.ng, DNS:google.nl, DNS:google.no, DNS:google.nr, DNS:google.nu, DNS:google.off.ai,
 DNS:google.pk, DNS:google.pl, DNS:google.pn, DNS:google.ps, DNS:google.pt, DNS:google.ro, DNS:google.rs, DNS:google.ru, DNS:google.rw, DNS:google.sc, DNS:google.s
e, DNS:google.sh, DNS:google.si, DNS:google.sk, DNS:google.sm, DNS:google.sn, DNS:google.so, DNS:google.sr, DNS:google.st, DNS:google.td, DNS:google.tel, DNS:googl
e.tg, DNS:google.tk, DNS:google.tl, DNS:google.tm, DNS:google.tn, DNS:google.to, DNS:google.tt, DNS:google.ua, DNS:google.us, DNS:google.uz, DNS:google.vg, DNS:goo
gle.vu, DNS:google.ws, DNS:googlecommerce.com, DNS:gstatic.com, DNS:urchin.com, DNS:youtu.be, DNS:youtube.com, DNS:youtubeeducation.com
            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://clients1.google.com/ocsp

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                62:2D:E9:85:63:74:56:2B:7B:BC:74:B0:55:B0:BE:1A:A4:67:87:01
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:4A:DD:06:16:1B:BC:F6:68:B5:76:F5:81:B6:BB:62:1A:BA:5A:81:2F

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.5.1
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         90:ac:be:c3:95:c1:56:ae:9c:02:76:f9:da:76:6b:bd:45:34:
         60:d3:fe:7f:f7:bb:72:6b:25:b2:75:88:8a:c0:06:74:ba:e2:
         e5:da:71:bd:1b:9d:5b:04:e3:ea:67:fb:4f:f3:b2:05:c1:6f:
         dd:c0:7b:cf:87:6e:31:f5:88:23:31:ea:c1:e1:18:5f:f7:b1:
         4b:b1:97:98:f2:2c:8f:0b:e1:0d:33:a4:58:c6:4d:ac:c7:73:
         11:f9:3b:53:a4:d3:7c:08:e6:bd:87:41:0b:4f:4a:62:f4:68:
         c5:4a:d1:83:b5:94:55:56:db:b7:7f:fa:cd:68:73:58:32:05:
         b9:fd:45:55:95:a1:f5:4b:f0:29:23:33:e8:13:85:f8:d9:f5:
         ca:8e:b1:18:7b:0b:b8:28:b6:ba:ea:6b:42:f4:d0:d0:b5:da:
         aa:6d:4d:48:8e:c2:ac:97:04:12:c9:45:8f:96:40:60:14:2a:
         3c:62:cf:14:0c:e3:c2:82:af:a6:f9:14:8e:32:b3:b3:e2:19:
         d9:71:f4:67:3f:d0:95:bf:40:a1:a5:ab:bf:c6:ca:25:a0:a0:
         b9:c5:68:49:31:26:67:32:ca:15:35:0d:62:f8:ed:93:26:91:
         03:00:a7:97:24:bc:bc:74:19:ae:f4:89:7e:21:59:ca:16:3f:
         ac:b8:57:c6
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Here is what i see in Chrome**

[image: chrome www.google.pl cert detail]

Should i see same SHA-256 fingerprint in Chrome and OpenSSL Cli ? Thanks.

Comment: You should give more information like: what is the subject and serial number of the certificate and do they actually match between your browser and the openssl one. By the way I do not see the point of `echo | ... ` as echo with no args just produce a blank line, which will probably get ignored by openssl since you provided a connect argument.

Comment: Thanks. I added details in orignal post.
"echo |" prevents hang.

Comment: @Mvy once SSL/TLS connection is established, if it is (handshake successful), `s_client` reads from stdin and sends to the server, while reading from the server and writing to stdout, until EOF on stdin (unless you specify `-ign_eof`) or server closes the connection. `echo |` provides one empty line *followed by EOF* causing `s_client` to complete. Technically an empty line is an HTTP error, so `</dev/null` would be a tiny bit better; or `echo Q |` is treated as a special command that causes `s_client` to exit without sending any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use -servername in OpenSSL connect options as Google use multiple domain names.

> $ echo | openssl s_client **-servername www.google.pl** -connect
>   www.google.pl:443 |& openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout  SHA256
>   Fingerprint=E0:0B:85:15:B2:53:84:09:C3:EE:2E:CD:75:29:94:89:5D:0A:8F:75:0F:0F:94:0C:D7:35:95:6A:50:AF:4D:5B

This way, fingerprints in OpenSSL connect is same as shown as in Chrome browser :

E0 0B 85 15 B2 53 84 09 C3 EE 2E CD 75 29 94 89
5D 0A 8F 75 0F 0F 94 0C D7 35 95 6A 50 AF 4D 5B

As said by @M'vy before, depending your ISP you might get an other certificate.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6):

The Google servers choose different certificates based on which cipher suites the client offers in client_hello. The certificate your OpenSSL client gets contains a RSA public key. The certificate Chrome gets contains an Elliptic Curve public key. Hence, the certificates are different and consequently have different fingerprints.

Answer (score 0):

Google website uses multiple site to dispatch request.

It is more than probable than two different connection (I mean using two different internet connection) will be routed to different google front-end.

The different sites don't use the same certificate. As you can check on your output and screenshot, the serial number of the certificate does not match, meaning that you got provide two different certificate for the same address.

Then, it's perfectly normal to have different fingerprint for different certificates.

Comment: OK. From an other server (different country), i have  a different certificate fingerprint. But should i expect the same fingerprint from openssl cli and Chrome on the same computer ? Thanks

Comment: You don't compare the same certificates. So either you're not on the same server, or actually the remark of @Henrick is also interesting. Cipher suite will have different certificates.